# Why all goroutines are asleep - deadlock with ticker?

Tags: go

I've done go for some time but still can't figure why this deadlocks (https://play.golang.org/p/INeUl_ktMJA):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)

    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    for range t.C {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            t.Stop()
        default:
            print(".")
        }
    }

    cancel()
}
```

I'd expect the closed context to close the ticker channel which should exit the range loop and thus cleanup the context. Instead:

```
...fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        /Users/andig/htdocs/test.go:12 +0xaf
exit status 2
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/3078

Comment: Would appreciate a comment on the not very welcoming close notes. Seems to be a valid question, even if full docs were missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is written in the docs for Stop():

> Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a concurrent goroutine reading from the channel from seeing an erroneous "tick".

Comment: The error is in the line of `<- ctx.Done()` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @SaedSayedAhmed, deadlock is at the range over channel. when t.Stop() stops the goroutine, there is no other goroutine left to write to the channel, hence the deadlock. There can never be a deadlock at the select, because it has a default case.

Comment: I would have to disagree. The error pops up from that line, and I'm actually having the same issue with `ctx.Done()` and I don't even have a channel or `for range` in the whole implementation.

Comment: @SaedSayedAhmed, select has a default case. <-ctx.Done() will not be selected at all unless it is ready to be read from.